# Backbone simple use drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, backbone.js

I'm using default drag and drop inside a backbone application i'm listening event in my view like this :

```
"drop img.big-objet": "dragDropEvent",
"dragenter img.objet": "dragEnterLeaveEvent",
"dragleave img.big-objet": "dragEnterLeaveEvent",
"mousedown img.big-objet": "dragStartEvent",
"mouseup img.big-objet": "dragStopEvent",
"dragend img.big-objet": "dragStopEvent",
```

**With the associated method**

```
dragEnterLeaveEvent: function (event){
    object = $(event.target);
    object.addClass('hidden');
    $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).removeClass('hidden');
},

dragStartEvent: function (event) {
        object = $(event.target);
        object.addClass('objet-drag').removeClass('objet-hover');
    },

    dragStopEvent: function (event) {
        object = $(event.target);
        object.addClass('objet-hover').removeClass('objet-drag');
    },

objectHover: function(event){
    object = $(event.target);
        object.addClass('hidden');
    $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).removeClass('hidden');
},

dragDropEvent: function(event){
    alert('banana');
}
```

**And the associated html**

```
<img class="objet" id="small-objet01-level01" data-toggle="big-objet01-level01" src="img/content/small-objet01-level01.png" alt="" />
<img class="objet" id="small-objet02-level01" data-toggle="big-objet02-level01" src="img/content/small-objet02-level01.png" alt="" />
<img class="objet" id="small-objet03-level01" data-toggle="big-objet03-level01" src="img/content/small-objet03-level01.png" alt="" />
<img class="big-objet objet-hover hidden" id="big-objet01-level01" draggable="true" data-toggle="small-objet01-level01" src="img/content/big-objet01-level01.png" alt="" />
<img class="big-objet objet-hover hidden" id="big-objet02-level01" draggable="true" data-toggle="small-objet02-level01" src="img/content/big-objet02-level01.png" alt="" />
<img class="big-objet objet-hover hidden" id="big-objet03-level01" draggable="true" data-toggle="small-objet03-level01" src="img/content/big-objet03-level01.png" alt="" />
```

All of my events work correctly but not the drop event. So my question is how make it work ?

Comment: What do you gain by integrating this with Backbone vs setting the callbacks in the initialization object?  In my Backbone applications I tend to set up things like drag-drop in the initialization or render method and don't utilize the 'events' hash for them.  Is it better to integrate for garbage collection purposes or something else?

Comment: have you used jquery UI libraries for draggable and droppable ?

Comment: Not at this moment but I'm thinking about

Comment: I tried using `over` and `out` events with backbone, but what I needed was `dragenter` and `dragleave`. Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix by using JQuery UI libraries instead of HTML5 drag and drop.

I put this in my render method:

```
$('#overlay-objet img').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: _.bind(function(event, ui) {
      object = $(event.target);
      if (object.attr("data-val") != undefined){
        objectDrag = object.attr('data-val').toString();
        objectDrop = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-val').toString();
        object.addClass('hidden');
        $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).removeClass('hidden');
        this.dragDropEvent(objectDrag + objectDrop);
      }
    }, this),
    over: _.bind(function(event,ui){
      object = $(event.target);
      object.addClass('hidden');
      $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).removeClass('hidden');
    }, this),
    out: _.bind(function(event,ui){
      object = $(event.target);
      object.removeClass('hidden');
      $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).addClass('hidden');
    }, this) // Edit mercredi soir ajouter ,this dans chaque callback
  });

$('img.big-objet').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly looking over it it looks like you are missing the comma after the 'objectHover'.